# URL rewriting test for beginners

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I was just learning to rewrite urls but got error on my first step. 
My current url is:

`http://localhost/tutorials/blog.php?blogId=30`

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^blogs/([0-9]+)/?$    blog.php?blogId=$1    [NC,L]
```

According to guide after this code my url should look like
`http://localhost/tutorials/blogs/30/`   but it's still same so where I am going wrong. Both `.htaccess` and `blog.php` are in same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provides you an alternate way to work on URLs of the form `http://localhost/tutorials/blogs/30/`. It does not format the uglier URL to pretty/friendly one.

Use the following to achieve that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*blog)\.php\?blogId=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1s/%2/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^blogs/([0-9]+)/?$ blog.php?blogId=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: when i open blog ,no content even header file has lost it's styling?

Comment: @bɪˈɡɪnə Sorry about that. Fixed the pattern now.

Comment: thanks got my content back :) but stylesheet still missing

Comment: @bɪˈɡɪnə How are the stylesheets being included? You'd probably have to rely on the `<base href>` element in the pages.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewriting can be one of the best and quickest ways to improve the usability and search friendliness of your site. It can also be the source of near-unending misery and suffering. Definitely worth playing carefully with it - lots of testing is recommended. With great power comes great responsibility, and all that.

Refer this article https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/.